# xcode SimpleAudioEngine increasing volume

Tags: xcode

increase volume with SimpleAudioEngine. I tried adding
`playBackgroundMusic.volume = 1.0f;` to my code but no luck

`[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background_menu.mp3" loop:YES];`

Comment: Look where the code sets the volume, and use that property. I'd bet it is something like `[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].musicVolume = 1.0f;`.

Answer (score 0):

Examples here. Also note that you have to load the music first before you can change the volume: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:cookbook

> Use preloadBackgroundMusic to reduce start up time when you call playBackgroundMusic. You can also do this to ensure there is a background music object to set properties against (such as volume) before you call playBackgroundMusic.

```
SimpleAudioEngine *sae = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
if (sae != nil) {
    [sae preloadBackgroundMusic:@"mula_tito_on_timbales.mp3"];
    if (sae.willPlayBackgroundMusic) {
        sae.backgroundMusicVolume = 0.5f;
    }
}
```